# How to do word wrap in a DevExpress TcxGrid?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, word-wrap, tcxgrid

I've got a long line of text that would be a lot easier to view if it would just word wrap around multiple lines, but I can't seem to find the option for it.  Does anyone know how to enable word-wrap functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the OptionsView.CellAutoHeight of the view you're working on?

From the help: "If the widths of the View’s columns are insufficient to display their entire content, then text clipping occurs.  Use the CellAutoHeight property to prevent this.  If this property value is True, then the cell content is displayed in multiple lines where necessary."

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I just wish the CX grid wasn't such a pain to work with.  Too many layers to dig through... :(

Comment: I hear you. I've been working with the cxGrid pretty extensively for the past 18 months and I'm still figuring it out... worth it though.

Comment: Agree about that, Mason. Too powerful yet too complex to fully absorp all its features.